# Kotlin deprecated annotation replaces this with class name

Tags: kotlin, annotations, deprecated

I have a method `fun logError(message: String)` and I want to replace it with a new method, which accepts `sender` object i.e. `fun logError(sender: Any, message: String)`. If I make it like this:

```
@Deprecated(
            message = "Use method with sender instead.",
            replaceWith = ReplaceWith("Logger.logError(this, message)"))
```

Then in place, when I replace it - I'm getting it like this `Logger.logError(Logger, message)`, which is not what was intended, how can I preserve `this` when replacing deprecated method?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for this annotation, my reading is that the "ReplaceWith" function identifies the section of text to be replaced to correct the out of date item and the text it should be replaced with.

If I'm right about that, it seems to me that the "replaceWith" clause in this instance should be

```
replaceWith = ReplaceWith("message", "sender: Any, message")
```

Not sure if this is simply a change in the three years since the question was posted.